# Where's IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy declared?

Tags: generics, extension-methods, ienumerable

Sorry for being lazy but where's IEnumerable.OrderBy declared. I know it's an extension method but where, in which class is it declared?

PS: Opening reflector...

Comment: Being lazy is a bad excuse, this kind of content doesn't really help make the site a better resource for the community.

Answer (score 2):

A "Go to Definition" click shows that it is declared on `System.Linq.Enumerable`